# i am using REST API to index data into elastic search but getting an error..please check

Tags: elasticsearch

i first used localhost:9200 and it displayed perfectly fine the problem is when i index some data

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It says you are using PUT but the only method allowed is POST.

Comment: If you use PUT you need to add an ID at the end of the URL. Otherwise you need to use POST and ES will auto-generate an ID

Comment: thanks for replying..but when i use POST i get this {"error":"Content-Type header [text/plain;charset=UTF-8] is not supported","status":406}

Comment: bro it worked..thanks

Comment: @ShubhamRanjan how did this work for you  ?

Comment: @Velu I reinstalled Elastic Search using terminal , then it worked.